# Algorithms - Time complexity of recursive multiplication function

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

I had this as a test question to evaluate the time complexity of the below recursive method.

```
def multiply(x,y)
if y = 0: 
   return 0
z = multiply(x,y/2) 
if y is even:
   return 2z
else :
   return x + 2z
```

I had written log(n) as the number y keeps decreasing by 2 and the recursive call will soon end as it meets the condition.

Comment: You sure the solution is not log(y)?

Comment: Professor did not give me any marks for that. I am still of the opinion that it should be log(y)*. Before discussing with him i wanted expert opinion.

Comment: If you run that in Python with `multiply(10, 2)` you will get a recursion error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: The second line, in the code y = 0, you sure it was not y == 0?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja that is what I have assumed too.

Comment: its y=0 in the question - I am sure its not a trick question though.

Comment: Agree with you @gil.fernandes considering there are no compilation issues and errors. How will we identify the complexity?

Comment: The complexity would be `infinite` if that's the case.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is meant to have a zero check as stated above in the question, this function will never terminate.

Here is a working python version:

```
def multiply(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    z = multiply(x,y/2)
    if y % 2 == 0:
        return 2 * z
    else :
        return x + 2 * z
```

Whatever you feed into it: this will end in a recursion error. So complexity is infinite. Perhaps this is a trick question.

If however what your teacher meant was something like this:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    if 0.01 > y > -0.01:
        return 0
    z = multiply(x, y / 2)
    if y % 2 == 0:
        return 2 * z
    else:
        return x + 2 * z
```

then complexity looks indeed like `log(n)`.

Here is some complexity benchmarking code which counts the number of operations:

```
counter = 0

def multiply(x, y):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if 0.01 > y > -0.01:
        return 0
    z = multiply(x, y / 2)
    if y % 2 == 0:
        return 2 * z
    else:
        return x + 2 * z

for i in range(1000):
    counter = 0
    multiply(1, i)
    print(i, counter)
```

It prints a sequence of numbers which is logarithmic in nature:

```
0 1
1 8
2 9
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 11
7 11
8 11
9 11
10 11
11 12
12 12
13 12
14 12
15 12
16 12
17 12
18 12
19 12
20 12
21 13
22 13
23 13
24 13
25 13
26 13
27 13
28 13
29 13
30 13
...
```